# Unable to save date into a SharePoint DateTime column using python script

Tags: python, date, sharepoint

I have a script that writes today's date into a SharePoint Column. this Column is of DateTime datetype "Date only" i tried many ways but it never saves today's date and the column is always empty

- I tried to pass a fixed string as "4/12/2023", "4/12/2023 12:00 AM", "4/12/2023 12:00:00 AM" yet when i run the script nothing is saved into this data
- I tried dynamic code as the following: = now_utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

**So i need to know how i can create a code in python that saves today's date into a datetime date only datatype into a SharePoint**

- I tried to pass a fixed string as "4/12/2023", "4/12/2023 12:00 AM", "4/12/2023 12:00:00 AM" yet when i run the script nothing is saved into this data
- I tried dynamic code as the following: = now_utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

i even tried more codes yet the column is always empty

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: try:
    
        list_name = "list"
        lists = ctx.web.lists
        query = lists.filter("Title eq '{0}'".format(list_name))
        result = ctx.load(query)
        ctx.execute_query()
        list_obj = query[0]
 # Convert local time to UTC
        tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Beirut')
        now_local = datetime.datetime.now(tz)
        now_utc = now_local.astimezone(pytz.utc)
        item_properties["Date"] = now_utc.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
        item = list_obj.add_item(item_properties)
        ctx.execute_query()